# Submit a form in a modal using ng-bootstrap

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm just trying to submit a form in a modal with ng-boostrap, and it is much more complicated than it should be, I used ng-boostrap to avoid JQuery code that is never elegant, but it has a cost... I'm a bit frustrated, easy and common stuff should be more straightforward.

Here is my Modal Template:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <ng-template #newCategory let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
    <div class="modal-header bg-primary text-white text-uppercase">
      <h4 class="modal-title">{{ 'core.create_a_new_category' | translate | uppercase }}</h4>
      <button type="button" class="close text-white" aria-label="Close"  (click)="d()">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="c('Save click')">
        Add Category
      </button>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</form>

<!-- Button that trigger modal -->
<div align="center" class="mt-2">
  <span class="mr-1">{{ 'core.want_to_create_custom_category' | translate }}</span>
  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary" (click)="open(newCategory)">
    {{ 'core.add_custom_category' | translate }}
  </button>
</div>
```

My Component :

```
export class NewCategoryModalComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private modalService: NgbModal  ) {
  }

  open(content) {
    this.modalService.open(content, {size: 'lg', centered: true}).result.then((result) => {
      this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
    }, (reason) => {
      this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
    });
  }
}
```

With this approach, you have to put the button that opens the modal inside the modal component which is not so great.

With that code, I can open and close the modal ( it took me 2 hours ), but now, my onSubmit() event is not intercept anymore, so the action is not done.

What am I missing ?

Comment: To make your life easier, define the [modal content as a component](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples#component) instead of a template. See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m31wbh) for a demo.

Comment: Ok, I could do it Tx :D Please put it as answer !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a component as the modal content could be easier than using a template. The procedure is shown in the [ng-bootstrap documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples#component). The code below can be tested in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m31wbh).

**Modal content component:**

The `NgbdModalContent` component below contains the form, with a header, body and footer. It will be the content of the modal. Clicking the submit button will trigger the `ngSubmit` Angular event.

HTML:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Hi there!</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Hello, {{name}}!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button  class="btn btn-outline-success" (click)="onClick()">Submit</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="activeModal.close('Close click')">Close</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Code:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModal, NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class NgbdModalContent {
  @Input() name;

  constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) { }

  onClick() {
    console.log("Submit button was clicked!");
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log("Form was submitted!");
    this.activeModal.close("Submit");
  }
}
```

**Modal component:**

The modal component has a method that allows to open the modal with an instance of the `NgbdModalContent` component as its content:

```
@Component({
  ...
})
export class NgbdModalComponent {

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) { }

  open() {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(NgbdModalContent);
    modalRef.componentInstance.name = 'World';
  }
}
```

**AppModule:**

The `NgbdModalContent` component must be included in the `entryComponents` of the module:

```
import { NgbdModalComponent, NgbdModalContent } from './modal-component';
...

@NgModule({
  ...
  declarations: [NgbdModalComponent, NgbdModalContent, ...],
  entryComponents: [NgbdModalContent]
}) 
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario, i wanted to have the template in the parent component, and have the child as a form only. In this scenario, it requires that the module is declared in the child component so it doesnt work. what i did is use a event from child to update the parent with status to close it.

Parent:

```
    <ng-template #content let-modal>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <app-add-edit-emp [emp]="emp" (successEvent)='AddEditUpdateStatus($event)'  *ngIf="ActivateAddEditEmpComp"></app-add-edit-emp>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Child:
declare your output parameters:

```
@Output() successEvent = new EventEmitter();
```

emit the event:

```
this.successEvent.emit(true);
```

Handle it in parent:

```
AddEditUpdateStatus(success){
    if(success){
      this.modalService.dismissAll("success");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

if we put  tag as rootNode like below code, we lose body scroll

```
<form [formGroup]="stockWatchListFrom" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <p class="modal-title">Title</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col">
        <label>WatchListName</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onSubmit()">Confirm</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm ml-3">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

i prefer this example

```
  <div class="modal-header">
    <p class="modal-title">Title</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form [formGroup]="stockWatchListFrom" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col">
          <label>WatchListName</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onSubmit()">Confirm</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm ml-3">Cancel</button>
  </div>
```